# Why does this code not work as "expected" when attempting to "watermark" using PyPDF2?

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I am merging PDF pages (watermark style) such that an original base pdf outline is populated with text from another pdf.

The base pdf is ONE page that provides a header.
The text pdf is a TWO page pdf that has text on page 1 and text on page 2.

I am attempting to produce a TWO page pdf output that has the base header on each page and the corresponding text from each page of the original text pdf.

However, when implementing the below code, the result is a two page pdf with the header on each page, but BOTH pages of text on each of the two pages of the resulting pdf.

```
# file1 # Pdf file - text of two pages
# file2 # Pdf file - base header of one page
# fileO # Output file

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

textpdf = PdfFileReader(open(file1,'rb')) # Reads the text PDF into PyPDF2
basepdf = PdfFileReader(open(file2,'rb')) # Reads the base PDF into PyPDF2
output = PdfFileWriter() # Creates the ouput object in PyPDF2
num_pages = textpdf.getNumPages() # The number of pages in the text file

for page in range(num_pages):
    basepdf_page = basepdf.getPage(0)
    basepdf_page.mergePage(textpdf.getPage(page))
    output.addPage(basepdf_page)    

outputpdf = open(fileO,'wb')
output.write(outputpdf)
outputpdf.close()
```

I have tried placing this line of code:

```
basepdf_page = basepdf.getPage(0)
```

above the for loop, but this does not change anything.

I have also tried the method the 'other way round' writing the base header file onto each page of the text file, but the problem with this is that the white space of the base header file basically overwrites the text.  This way round at least the text overwrites the base header file white space.

If further information is required, please let me know.  Meantime, I shall keep looking for a solution!

Thanks!

---

Update:  If I refresh the basepdf object each time, by moving the code that instantiates that object into the for loop, then it works as expected, so I have solved the problem, but I would still like to understand why it did not work as "expected" the first time!

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

textpdf = PdfFileReader(open(file1,'rb')) # Reads the text PDF into PyPDF2
num_pages = textpdf.getNumPages() # The number of pages in the text file

output = PdfFileWriter() # Creates the ouput object in PyPDF2

for page in range(num_pages):
    basepdf = PdfFileReader(open(file2,'rb')) # Reads the base PDF into PyPDF2
    basepdf_page = basepdf.getPage(0)
    basepdf_page.mergePage(textpdf.getPage(page))
    output.addPage(basepdf_page)

outputpdf = open(fileO,'wb')
output.write(outputpdf)
outputpdf.close()
```

Thanks!

Comment: It feels like I need to "flush" something in order to make this work...